# Is it possible to render 180º equirectangular with eevee engine?

Tags: camera, eevee-render-engine

I'd like to make the switch to eevee as it is more suitable for my needs, but the panoramic fov lens in eevee only goes up to 173º. In cycles I use a panoramic lens with equirectangular projection at +/- 90º for both longitude and latitude to create 180º renders.

The equirectangular camera settings are essential to create renders for virtual reality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this isn’t possible at present - but has been asked before and is expected to be a planned feature - see https://blenderartists.org/t/will-eevee-support-vr-equirectangular-rendering/699631 in particular :

> At last blender conference, there was a talk about the benefits of using Grease pencil + VR to create a scene.
>   There are devs dedicated to VR. I don’t doubt that VR support for EEVEE is a goal they want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that the panoramic lens in 2.8 alpha is a placeholder and does nothing at the moment. I'm guessing they have plans to get to it in the future.