# How to render an Equirectangular Panoramic image with Eevee

Tags: camera, eevee-render-engine

I want to use Eevee to render 360 panoramic images. I do not want to use cycles because of the render time for my project. I tried searching google and this site but the last time this was asked was about 2 years ago: [Is it possible to render 180º equirectangular with eevee engine?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122061/is-it-possible-to-render-180%C2%BA-equirectangular-with-eevee-engine)

My only thought is to create multiple cameras, render each camera and then stitch together in another program. Is there an easier and faster way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this [VRRenderer script by EternalTrail](https://github.com/EternalTrail/eeVR) that works okay for rendering a stationary camera. However it does not animate and the camera cannot be parented to another empty or object. (Correction - it can render an animated camera or imported camera, please read the update below)

Here's a video explaining how it works.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ND8T5_VCcN0

I have tried installing it as a addon as described in the video but it didn't work for me, what worked is opening the python script directly in the scripting tab in Blender and then running the script. Following that you should be able to see the eeVR tab on the side of the viewport. You have to save the blend file for it to run and also it writes the renders in PNG and into the same folder of the of the blend file. Seams will appear if you turn on AO and bloom in Eevee. Turning on overscan will apparently fix the problem but I have yet to try it.

Guess I'll have to wait for the Blender developers to come out with a dedicated Panoramic renderer for EEVEE. Cycles is good but the render times just take way too long when time is limited.

Update after some experiments.

I have trying to use an imported alembic cache export from Maya and although I can see the camera animated, the VRrender script does not want to render from the camera. As explained earlier, this is a limitation in the script. I tried deleting all the cameras and used a single camera and the script automatically renders to that camera. I tried manually keyframe animating it and the renders correspond to the keyframed animation. Eventually I figured out from other forum posts that I can just duplicate the alembic exported camera, delete its alembic constraint, then apply a transform constraint to follow the alembic constraint camera. Following that I select the duplicated camera, then go to Object => Animation => Bake Action to bake the keyframes into every frame. In the Bake Action options, I turned on only Visual Keying and Clear Parents. My Camera animation had over 2700 frames so it took a while for the keys to be baked. This is the workaround I'll use until the official Panoramic EeVee render is available.